# jQuery version trouble

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have already used up 2 hours of searching for similar problems and I haven't been successful. So I am really hoping that someone is able to help me out.

I want to use 2 jquery tools at the same time:
http://fancyapps.com
http://adis.ro/jquery/slideup/

First one is using the newest jQuery
second one version 1.6.

They each don't work with the version provided by the other tool.

I have tried the possibility of using two versions at a time, but since I am not a professional who just started out this thing, I am really hoping on you guys.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Try looking here: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) anyways is not recommended to use 2 jQuery versions. Why should you?

Comment: migrate plugin which works on older jquery version

Comment: I bet both work with jQuery v1.8.3

Comment: They do!!! Thanks JFK!

Answer (score 0):

Include your scripts in this order :

Newest jQuery
First Tool
Jquery 1.6
Second Tool

Or

Jquery 1.6
Second Tool
Newest jQuery
First Tool

it should work